# More flexible format in ISO8601DateFormatter Date

Tags: swift

I'm currently converting this kind of date format: `"2021-11-26T15:48:43Z"` to `"2021-11-26"`

1. How can I flip it? So it looks like: `11-26-2021`
2. What if I wanted to get only the time? Like: `11:13pm`

This is my code:

```
func formatDateToStringMMDDYYYY(tempDay: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    let timeZone = TimeZone.current
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: tempDay)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = timeZone
    dateFormatter.formatOptions = [
        .withFullDate,
        .withDashSeparatorInDate
    ]
    let dateFormatted = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
    
    return dateFormatted
}
```

I was looking for answers in [apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/iso8601dateformatter/1643324-formatoptions) but I don't see an option for this. Is there another way to accomplish it?

EDIT:

I tried reformating the date after the initial format but it's returning nil, this is what I tried:

```
let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
dateFormatter2.amSymbol = "AM"
dateFormatter2.pmSymbol = "PM"

let date2 = dateFormatter2.date(from: dateFormatted)
```

Comment: You could use a separate formatter for the output formatting and use a custom date format.

Comment: I tried that but it returns nil, see my edited answer @JoakimDanielson

Comment: The `ISO8601DateFormatter` doesn't know am/pm nor a different order of the date components as `yyyyMMdd`.  You have to convert `return dateFormatter2.string(from: date)`.

Comment: It worked! I'm preparing the solution and I'll post it, thanks! @vadian

Comment: I of course meant you should use the parsed Date object in the second formatter and not the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution to convert it to AM/PM time, and the same applies for the other:

Output style: `10:48 PM`

```
func formatIS08601DateToStringHourMin(tempDay: String) -> String {
    let ISO8601DateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    let date = ISO8601DateFormatter.date(from: tempDay)
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
    dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
    
    let finalDateFormatted = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
    
    return finalDateFormatted
}
```

Thank you @vadian & @Joakim_Danielson for the help.